# running the same function with different parameters in different threads, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous

I`m trying to exectue multiple dictionary searches in multiple threads.

I've got a findBinaryWord(..) function which I would like to run twice or x times, each one on a different thread, each function get's 2 parameters, this should return true or false if word was found.

Tried to use async & webhamsters
http://www.hamsters.io/, http://caolan.github.io/async/

but I was not able to find how I set several functions with variables to the function stack.

can someone please show me an example how that should be written?

I have tried the following:

#### translator.js

```
stack.push(dictionaryManager.findBinaryWord(data.word, translator.dictionaries[dictionary]["words"] ) );
```

and to start the stack

```
async.parallel( stack, function( err, result ) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

but I get an error:

### Uncaught TypeError: false is not a function

this is my function it gets word, a string, and an array where to search in, an array of words.

#### dictionaryManager.js

```
function findBinaryWord( word, dict ) {..

    // If we've found the word, stop now
    if ( word === found ) {
        foundit = true;
        callback(null, foundit);
}
..
.
// Nothing was found
callback(null, false);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded.

Comment: The async module should only be used for asynchronous functions. If your `findBinaryWord` is synchronous, don't use callbacks, and don't try to run it in parallel.

Comment: What do you mean?
findBinaryWord is an asynchronous function.
I need to run two instances of it in paralell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `stack` array you are not actually pushing a function but its results, which i think is `false` hence the error.

try it like this. (added `callback` as third parameter to `findBinaryWord`)

```
 stack.push(function(callback) { 
     dictionaryManager.findBinaryWord(data.word, translator.dictionaries[dictionary]["words"], callback);
 });
```

and change your `findBinaryWord` to accept `callback` as parameter

```
function findBinaryWord( word, dict, callback) {
    // ...
    // If we've found the word, stop now
    if ( word === found ) {
        foundit = true;
        callback(null, foundit);
    }
}
```

Comment: now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined`,
I require async only in my translator.js.
should I include it also on `dictionaryManager.js`

?

Comment: amazing, exactly what I did, it seems like it working however I always get [false, false] value as return for some reason...

still manglling with it

Comment: for some reason the I get only 1 callback, the last one.
Could it be that only the last function in the stack runs?